# Get transaction detail after successful paymemt

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to get the user entered details back from paypal.

**Q 1)** How to get email address and other details from paypal ?

**Q 2)** system generated mail should be sent from success case or from ipn case ?

**Q 3)** After successful transaction i am getting message on paypal screen - 'we will send a confirmation email to foo@email.com' .but i am not getting any email at all.

Note: I am testing on sandbox.

**Q 4)** I am not shipping any item to buyer's address.So is it possible to remove shipping address from paypal screen ?

```
<?php

switch($action){

    case "process": // case process insert the form data in DB and process to the paypal
            echo "in process";
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `purchases` (`invoice`, `product_id`, `product_name`, `product_quantity`, `product_amount`, `payer_fname`, `payer_lname`, `payer_address`, `payer_city`, `payer_state`, `payer_zip`, `payer_country`, `payer_email`, `payment_status`, `posted_date`) VALUES ('".$_POST["invoice"]."', '".$_POST["product_id"]."', '".$_POST["product_name"]."', '".$_POST["product_quantity"]."', '".$_POST["product_amount"]."', '".$_POST["fname"]."', '".$_POST["lname"]."', '".$_POST["address"]."', '".$_POST["city"]."', '".$_POST["state"]."', '".$_POST["zip"]."', '".$_POST["ccCountry"]."', '".$_POST["email"]."', 'pending', NOW())");
        $this_script = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        $p->add_field('business', PAYPAL_EMAIL_ADD); // Call the facilitator eaccount
        $p->add_field('cmd', $_POST["cmd"]); // cmd should be _cart for cart checkout
        $p->add_field('upload', '1');
        $p->add_field('return', $this_script.'?action=success'); // return URL after the transaction got over
        $p->add_field('cancel_return', $this_script.'?action=cancel'); // cancel URL if the trasaction was cancelled during half of the transaction
        $p->add_field('notify_url', $this_script.'?action=ipn'); // Notify URL which received IPN (Instant Payment Notification)
        $p->add_field('currency_code', $_POST["currency_code"]);
        $p->add_field('invoice', $_POST["invoice"]);
$j=1;
                 for ($i = 0; $i < $N; $i++) {

        $p->add_field('item_name_'.$j, $_POST["product_name"]);
        $p->add_field('item_number_'.$j, $test[$i]);
        $p->add_field('quantity_'.$j, $_POST["product_quantity"]);
                $p->add_field('amount_'.$j, $_POST["product_amount"]);
                $j++;
                 }


        $p->add_field('first_name', $_POST["fname"]);
        $p->add_field('last_name', $_POST["lname"]);
        $p->add_field('address1', $_POST["address"]);
        $p->add_field('city', $_POST["city"]);
        $p->add_field('state', $_POST["state"]);
        $p->add_field('country', $_POST["country"]);
        $p->add_field('zip', $_POST["zip"]);
        $p->add_field('email', $_POST["email"]);
        $p->submit_paypal_post(); // POST it to paypal
        $p->dump_fields(); // Show the posted values for a reference, comment this line before app goes live
    break;

    case "success": // success case to show the user payment got success
        echo '<title>Payment Done Successfully</title>';
        echo '<style>.as_wrapper{
    font-family:Arial;
    color:#333;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:20px;
    border:2px dashed #17A3F7;
    width:600px;
    margin:0 auto;
}</style>
';      echo '<div class="as_wrapper">';
        echo "<h1>Payment Transaction Done Successfully</h1>";
        echo '<h4>Use this below URL in paypal sandbox IPN Handler URL to complete the transaction</h4>';
        echo '<h3>http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?action=ipn</h3>';
        echo '</div>';
                echo 'email'.$_POST['email'];
                echo 'product name'.$_POST['item_name'];


                   if (!$mail->Send()) {
                        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                    } else {
echo "Message has been sent";
                    }
//==================================================================================================================
    break;

    case "cancel": // case cancel to show user the transaction was cancelled
        echo "<h1>Transaction Cancelled";
    break;

    case "ipn": // IPN case to receive payment information. this case will not displayed in browser. This is server to server communication. PayPal will send the transactions each and every details to this case in secured POST menthod by server to server. 
        $trasaction_id  = $_POST["txn_id"];
        $payment_status = strtolower($_POST["payment_status"]);
        $invoice        = $_POST["invoice"];
        $log_array      = print_r($_POST, TRUE);
        $log_query      = "SELECT * FROM `paypal_log` WHERE `txn_id` = '$trasaction_id'";
        $log_check      = mysql_query($log_query);
        if(mysql_num_rows($log_check) <= 0){
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `paypal_log` (`txn_id`, `log`, `posted_date`) VALUES ('$trasaction_id', '$log_array', NOW())");
        }else{
            mysql_query("UPDATE `paypal_log` SET `log` = '$log_array' WHERE `txn_id` = '$trasaction_id'");
        } // Save and update the logs array
        $paypal_log_fetch   = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($log_query));
        $paypal_log_id      = $paypal_log_fetch["id"];

if ($p->validate_ipn()){ // validate the IPN, do the others stuffs here as per your app logic
                mysql_query("UPDATE `purchases` SET `trasaction_id` = '$trasaction_id ', `log_id` = '$paypal_log_id', `payment_status` = '$payment_status' WHERE `invoice` = '$invoice'");
                $subject = 'Instant Payment Notification - Recieved Payment';
                $p->send_report($subject); // Send the notification about the transaction
                    echo 'email'.$_POST['payer_email'];
                    echo 'product name'.$_POST['item_name'];

//==================================================================================================================


   if (!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            } else {
echo "Message has been sent";
                    }

        }else{
            $subject = 'Instant Payment Notification - Payment Fail';
            $p->send_report($subject); // failed notification
        }
    break;
}
?>
```

Comment: Q1: Please give us more information about how you are integrating with PayPal. What payment product are you using (express checkout, RESTful payments, adaptive payments, etc)? Cannot answer fully without this.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot answer fully without more information about the PayPal integration, but:

Q1: PayPal offers buyer information on IPNs and in the responses to most of the relevant API calls (DoExpressCheckout, etc). In some cases it has separate dedicated calls to get buyer information even before the payment is completed (e.g. GetExpressCheckout). Can't say more without knowing which payment product/api you are integrating to.

Q2: Emails are sent upon successful payment, whether or not a seller uses IPNs. The IPN and email are separate features, unrelated to each other.

Q3:  Sandbox accounts send only sandbox emails (to prevent people from mistaking them for real payment emails). Look for how to view your sandbox emails within the PayPal sandbox.

Q4: Yes this is possible with many PayPal products, but the specifics vary with which product you are integrating with. E.g. you may pass a &shipping=0 in the POST parameters, or you may need to set NoShipping=True... read the docs for the specific PayPal operation you are using to set up/redirect the user into a PayPal authorization flow.